# Update table with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm using Ajax to update table, when I hit the first request to edit or delete data in the system, it's works. After update the table with Ajax, I don't know what happens. The add, edit and delete stop working more.

```
function tabela(dados){
            var template = "<thead><tr> <th>ID</th><th>Nome</th><th>Status</th><th>E-mail</th> <th>Editar</th> <th>Excluir</th> </tr></thead><tbody>";
            var templateContrato = "<tr><td><i class='fa fa-circle' title='OK'></i><span class='statusicon'>#ID#</span></td><td>#NOME#</td><td>#STATUS#</td><td>#EMAIL#</td><td ><div id='EdContrato'> <div id='#EDITAR#'> Editar </div> </div></td><td class='contrato'> <div id='ExContrato'> <div id='#EXCLUIR#'> Excluir </div> </div></td></tr>";
            for (i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
                aux = templateContrato;
                aux = aux.replace('#ID#',dados[i].id_contrato);
                aux = aux.replace('#NOME#', dados[i].nome ? dados[i].nome:'');
                aux = aux.replace('#STATUS#',dados[i].status ? dados[i].status:'');
                aux = aux.replace('#EMAIL#', dados[i].email ? dados[i].email:'');
                aux = aux.replace('#EDITAR#', dados[i].id_contrato);
                aux = aux.replace('#EXCLUIR#', dados[i].id_contrato);

                template += aux;
            }                
            template +="</tbody>"
            $("#idContrato").html(template);
        }

        $("#btnAdicionar").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var nome = $("input[name=nome]").val();
            var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
            var status = $("input[name=status]").val();

            $.ajax({
                 type:'POST',
                 url:'/adicionar',
                data:{nome:nome, email:email, status:status},
                success:function(data){
               tabela(data);
            }
            });
            $("input[name=nome]").val("");
            $("input[name=email]").val("");
            $("input[name=status]").val("");
        });
```

Doesn't show any error.

Comment: Your `click` event should be replaced with `on` event. You can search in SO or Google for this.

Comment: You are creating invalid HTML, by appending elements with the same ID multiple times in a loop. IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document, so go and fix that first of all.

Comment: Because you are creating the DOM Elements dynamically you must use event delegation [Whats that I hear you cry](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are creating the DOM Elements dynamically click event wont work after 1st reload of HTML.

You need to use event deligator or jquery "on" click

```
$( "#ExContrato" ).on( "click", function() {
  // logic here
});


$( "#EdContrato" ).on( "click", function() {
  // logic here
});
```

More [detail here](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thanks man, but it's not work. Do you have any ideia, the problem is don't show errors.